# Rails joins or preload belongs_to association from polymorphic model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, preload, polymorphism

my problem is following. How can I joins belongs_to association from polymorphic model

There is situation

opinion.rb

```
class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :opinionable, :polymorphic => true
    belongs_to :category
end
```

answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :opinions, :as => :opinionable
end
```

How can i do following

> Opinion.joins(:opinionabe).all

it will throw

> ArgumentError: You can't create a polymorphic belongs_to join without specifying the polymorphic class!

How can i specific which class i want to join?

Second question. How to preload it?

> Opinion.preload(:opinionable).all

works fine. It will do query for each class in belongs_to.

But. if i want to do something like

> Opinion.preload(:opinionable => :answer_form).all

there is problem because one model has this association and second hasn't. So it will throw exception.

So how i can do something like

> Opinion.preload(:answer => :answer_form, :another_belongs_to_model).all

?

Thanks, David!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you have not specified `opinionable_type:string` column for your Opinion model.

Try to update your migration in this manner:

```
class CreateOpinions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :opinions do |t|
      t.integer :opinionable_id
      t.string  :opinionable_type

      # ... other fields

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :opinions
  end
end
```

This will solve your second question and `Opinion.preload(:opinionable).all` should work well.

You cann't do joins on polymorphic association because they can be located in different tables, which are detected after `Opinion` model is loaded. That why model needs column `opinionable_type`.

If you try to do this you'll get next exception

> `ActiveRecord::EagerLoadPolymorphicError`: Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association `:opinionable`

UPD: Added magic join ^_^

```
class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :opinionable, :polymorphic => true

  belongs_to :opinionable_answer, :foreign_key => :opinionable_id, :class_name => "Answer"

  scope :by_type, lambda { |type| joins("JOIN #{type.table_name} ON #{type.table_name}.id = #{Opinion.table_name}.opinionable_id AND #{Opinion.table_name}.opinionable_type = '#{type.to_s}'") }
end
```

Example:

```
Opinion.by_type(Answer).to_sql
  => "SELECT \"opinions\".* FROM \"opinions\" JOIN answers ON answers.id = opinions.opinionable_id AND opinions.opinionable_type = 'Answer'"
```

Comment: Polyporhic works fine for me (have id and type column in table). Got your explanation why joins doesn't work. I missed that fact that model doesn't know which classes are in belongs_to.

Comment: Have idea. Is possible something like this f i know the class Opinion.joins([:opinionable, Answer]) ?

Comment: If you know concrete class, you can add something like: `belongs_to :opinionable_answer, :foreign_key => :opinionable_id, :class_name => "Answer"` into `Opinion` model. And then `Opinion.joins(:opinionable_answer)` should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't work because It will join Answer table by ids which are for another belongs model too. Query is `SELECT opinions.* FROM opinions INNER JOIN answers ON answers.id = opinions.opinionable_id` but i need add to join this `JOIN ... ON ... AND opinions.opinionable_type = 'Answer'`

Answer (score 16):

Actually if you just do

```
belongs_to :opinionable_answer, :foreign_key => :opinionable_id, :class_name => "Answer", conditions: { opinions: { opinionable_type: "Answer"}}
```

then you can do

```
Opinion.joins(:opinionable_answer).where(answers: { awesome: true})
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but I just spent an hour looking for the solution to a similar problem (Rails 3) and the only way I got it to work was the solution stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25966630/6878997

Which, in your case would be:

```
class Opinion < ActiveRecord::Base
  # The true polymorphic association
  belongs_to :opinionable, polymorphic: true

  # The trick to solve this problem
  has_one :self_ref, :class_name => self, :foreign_key => :id

  has_one :answer, :through => :self_ref, :source => :opinionable, :source_type => Answer
end
```

Seems tricky but this way you will be able to do multiple chained joins such as:

`joins(answer: :other_model)`.

And whenever `opinion.opinionable` is not an `Answer`, `opinion.answer` will return `nil`.

Hope it helps somebody!